# In Jenkins, how can parameters that contain spaces be referenced?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Google has failed to even lead me to a proper answer as to why spaces are permitted in names of Jenkins parameters, let alone how to reference them. Assuming it's not just a major oversight, how does one access these parameters?

For example, I have a string parameter named "IP Address". I could rename it "IP_Address" but I'm trying to avoid the underscores_as_spaces if I can.

I've tried to refer to this parameter using "${IP Address}", "IP Address" and even "IP\ Address" but nothing seems to work. Is there any way to actually reference these?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `params['IP Address']`.

Think of `params` as a Map containing a key `'IP Address'`. If the key didn't have a space, then you could use `params.IPAddress` or `params['IPAddress']`, but when there's a space, you can only use the latter syntax.

That syntax is also useful when you're computing the key name to look up, and have stored it in a variable:

```
final String myParam = "param${i}"
// can't say `params.myParam`
echo "Value is ${params[myParam]}"
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me. In my declarative pipeline (Jenkinsfile) I've tried to do a `when` clause like this: `when { expression { params['Force generate NuGet'] == "true" } }`, but when I run my job and provide a parameter value, it doesn't pick up the value I gave it. Are there any pitfalls I should be aware of, any things I might be doing wrong?